# Haskell sqrt - converting a list of Integer to Float

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, sqrt

I need some help with my program. It's supposed to sqrt all element of a Integer list and give back a list of Float, in 3 variants: 1) recursive, 2) list comprehensions, 3) higher-order functions. I've wrote first one, which works fine:

```
-- recursive:

sqrtL1 :: [Integer] -> [Float]
sqrtL1 [] = []
sqrtL1 (n:ns)  = (sqrt x) : sqrtL1(ns)
    where x = fromIntegral n :: Float

-- Listenkomprehension:

sqrtL2 :: [Integer] -> [Float]
sqrtL2 (n:ns) = [sqrt x | x <- ns]
    where x = fromIntegral n :: Float  --(it doesn't work tho)

-- Higher-order:

sqrtL3 :: [Integer] -> [Float]
sqrtL3 ns = map sqrt ns
```

but I'm getting troubles with converting in the next two cases. Could someone help me?

Comment: Note that you don't need (and shouldn't use!) parentheses in `sqrt x : sqrtL1 ns`. It's still correct of course in principle, but just not nice standard Haskell style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `sqrtL2` is `x` is not in scope outside the list comprehension.  You need to do the `fromIntegral` inside the list comprehension like this:

```
sqrtL2 ns = [sqrt (fromIntegral x) | x <- ns]
```

`sqrtL3` is fine except you don't have a `fromIntegral` anywhere and `sqrt` is `Floating a => a -> a` so it doesn't work with Integer.  So you need this instead:

```
map (sqrt . fromIntegral) ns
```

Comment: To clarify, it should be just `sqrtL2 ns = [sqrt (fromIntegral x) | x <- ns]`. In other words, change `(n:ns)` to `ns` and drop the `where` clause.